# Как использовать все команды Redis из под NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, redis

Есть такой модуль для ноды: https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis
Но в нем маловато методов для работы с redis, у редиса то много команд: http://redis.io/commands

Есть ли возможность юзать все команды редиса из под ноды?

p.s.
Например мне нужна была команда EXISTS, пришлось делать сначала get, смотреть что в нем... неудобно очень и не правильно я считаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Команда `exists` в `node_redis` [вообще-то есть](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis/blob/master/index.js#L976), и более того, даже [покрыта тестами](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis/blob/master/test/commands/exits.spec.js#L22) (в названии файла и ещё паре мест, что интересно, затаилась опечатка).

У них есть [скриптик](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis/blob/master/generate_commands.js), генерирующий список команд Redis из [официального источника](http://redis.io/commands.json).

Comment: А есть ли где-то список команд с описанием (что принимают/возвращают хотябы)?

Comment: Нажмите на ссылочку "официального источника". Можете распарсить этот JSON и собрать себе страничку =) А можете зайти на [redis.io](http://redis.io) и почитать в уже сформированном виде.

Answer (score 2):

Существует множество модулей для работы с Redis в Node.js. На сайте Redis есть даже список таких модулей ([источник](http://redis.io/clients#nodejs)):

- ioredis
- node_redis
- redis-node-client
- spade
- then-redis
- thunk-redis

Если `node_redis` чего-то не поддерживает, попробуйте другой модуль. А если ни один из них не подошел, никто не запрещает вам отправить pull-request с нужным вам функционалом в `node_redis` ;)